# NoMethodError In Rails Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the page template I've got:

```
<h1>Editing user</h1>

<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :forename %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :forename %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :surname %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :surname %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :address %>
        <%= f.text_field :address %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :postcode %>
        <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :contact_number %>
        <%= f.text_field :contact_number %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @user %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

The controller is actually sub-typed from the AdminController as there's a separate section as the following class declaration shows:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
```

with the edit method as follows:

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

With the error as follows:

```
undefined method `user_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x104369fe8>
```

and the following in my routes:

```
map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
    admin.resources :pages
    admin.resources :treatments
    admin.resources :users
    admin.resources :finances
end
```

So I'm a bit stuck, because it's the `form_for(@user)` that's doing it.  I've seen this before but have no idea how to diagnose it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a name spaced routes, you have to specify the name space in the `form_for` invocation.

```
<% form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f| %>
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002290) for more details.(Hint: Read the end of the `Resource-oriented style` section)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the name-spacing change the named paths so maybe to need to be explicit it in the form like this?

```
form_for (@user, :url => admin_user_path) do |f|
```

Comment: This will work not work for edit scenarios as the URL will be different.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu. I understand that but then you could use `edit_admin_user_path` for that case, no? But I like your answer better anyway

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You have to have additional code to check the state of the object and set the url accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the namespace you are using....the link would be

```
<% form_for @user, edit_admin_user_path(@user.id) do |f|%>
     .....
<% end %>
```

Do a `rake routes` to look at how routes look like for a namespaced controller